# Moving an object in hand back and forth creates a gravitational wave?

Tags: gravity, waves

Does moving an object in one's hand back and forth create a  wave?

It creates a changing gravitation field and that propagates as a wave, right?

How does that differ from a "gravitational" wave that has been measured recently?
Can both be detected in the same way?

Comment: Well the one with a small object is basically too weak to detect by any means today.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, moving objects do create gravitational waves. Let's look at this in detail:

Obviously one can never move just one object. Because of the conservation of momentum there are, at least, two objects moving and the center of mass stays in place. If you wiggle something with your arm, then your upper body has to compensate for that and part of the force you are exerting on that object is transferred to the Earth, which will move (unmeasurably) in the other direction. This means there is always relative motion of two or more objects around a center of mass.

The better way to move objects in such a fashion is by rotation. Nature does this with e.g. planetary systems and, more pronouncedly with binary stars, where the center of mass lies clearly outside of the two stars. In a technical gravitational antenna we could approximate this with two heavy masses on a stick that are being rotated very quickly. As it turns out, the faster we rotate these two masses, the more gravitational waves are being produced. Obviously this runs quickly into limits: fast rotating objects experience centrifugal forces which try to separate them (a better way to say that is that we need a centripetal force to keep them rotating on their trajectories around the center, but let's not be too detailed here). This sets tight limits of how fast objects can rotate before these forces are tearing them apart, which, in turn, limits how much power a practical gravitational antenna can emit.

In their chapter 36 "Laboratory Generators of Gravitational Waves" Misner, Thorne, Wheeler (MTW) are giving a number of formulas for the achievable gravitational wave power of such rotating systems. In particular they are analyzing the case of a steel beam rotating near its maximum tension. They find that a beam with a radius of 1m and a length of 20m and a total mass of approx. 490 tons can practically rotate at an angular velocity of approx. 28 radians/s. In more household units that's approx. 267rpm! I think we can both agree that nobody would want to be anywhere close that thing while it rotates, right? They then calculate that such a beam would emit a gravitational wave power of

$P_{GW}\approx 2.2\times10^{-22} erg/s = 2.2\times 10^{-29}J/s\approx 1.4\times10^{-10}eV/s$.

In other words, in terms of visible luminosity, this object would emit the equivalent of about one visible photon every 320 years in form of a gravitational wave.

Now that is one poorly performing transmitter!

Comment: Somewhere near Kip Thorne's office is a device labeled "gravitational wave generator" that consists of two masses (tens of grams) on a rod (about 10 cm) that probably rotates at less than 60 rpm when turned on.

Comment: +1! I'd like to upvote but I've used up my daily limit. Maybe tomorrow.. But when you say moving objects, you mean accelerating objects, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** - assuming the classical limit. Moving your hand back and forth causes a change in the curvature of spacetime, so it would cause gravitational waves. However, consider the mass of the bodies we observed, and the level of strain they caused in LIGO. A tiny gravitational wave created by your hand wouldn't cause anything detectable.

Further, I would imagine that the level of waves created by moving a small macroscopic object like your hand would be far dominated by any sort of quantum mechanical effect. We could do a calculation, but I think the point is that, because the gravitational coupling constant is so small, it takes massive events to produce gravitational waves. Otherwise, we would have things like the solar system decaying in small amounts of time (by radiating energy in the form of gravitational waves).